# Error using cvMinMaxLoc with IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv

While trying to compile an old code based on OpenCV-0.9.5 in Linux. It successfully built, but I got a cv error while running:

"OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_IS_IMAGE(arr) && (coi=cvGetImageCOI((const IplImage*)arr)-1) >= 0) in unknown function, file ........\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxmatrix.cpp"

I am not good at OpenCV and don't understand what this code really does. I just want to compile and run the project in: https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/cvEyeTracker

The project has lots of code and I cannot write all of them here, but I wrote and tested the error prone code simply in another project like this:

```
IplImage *eye_image; 

char *in_file = "E:\\eye.png";

eye_image = cvLoadImage(in_file, 1);

double min_value, max_value;

CvPoint min_loc, max_loc;

cvMinMaxLoc(eye_image, &min_value, &max_value, &min_loc, &max_loc);
```

It still produces the same error when calling cvMinMaxLoc. What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Note: I am using OpenCV 2.4.1 and Visual Studio 2013 with C++.

Comment: Don't use C obsolete api!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to convert all codes into C++ using OpenCV 2.4.1, but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Get a newer opencv version ;D latest is 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem that it was the input arguments of locations:

```
Mat eye_image; 

eye_image = imread("E:\\eye.png");

double min_value, max_value;

//CvPoint min_loc, max_loc;

minMaxLoc(eye_image, &min_value, &max_value);//, &min_loc, &max_loc);
```

The output is Max = 255, Min = 0. Why these min_loc and max_loc cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

@Miki I migrated to OpenCV 3.1, but the problem is to convert these lines:

```
CvSeq* contour=NULL;

CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

cvFindContours(threshold_image, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

OpenCV 3.1 include findContours method with different type of arguments:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

In addition, the code continues using contour variable as:

contour->total

Do you know what is the correct equivalence of CvSeq and CvMemStorage?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced codes with these:

```
vector<Point> contour;

vector<vector<Point>> storage;

findContours(threshold_image, storage, contour, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));
```

All codes were converted to OpenCV 3.1 and the project was successfully built, but the problem retains as I declared in the question. Writing all codes here is not reasonable, so I can send the whole Visual Studio 2013 project to whom want to debug.

Thanks